# Collection of all configurable products (which has children) and simple products ( not belonging to configurable product)

Tags: magento-1.8, module

How to get a collection of all configurable products and simple products ( not belonging to configurable product) in Magento custom module?

I have a custom code for getting all simple product which does belong to configurable product:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //or just the attributes you need

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('link_table' => 'catalog_product_super_link'),
    'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id',
    array('product_id')
);
$collection->getSelect()->where('link_table.product_id IS NULL');
```

And also have code for getting all configurable products:

```
$result = array();
$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($collectionConfigurable as $configurProduct)
{
    $Title=$configurProduct->getName();
    $id=$configurProduct->getId();
    $result[] = array('value'=>$id,'label'=>$Title);
}
return $result;
```

I want to get a collection of above both.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. My new code is following:

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$ConfigureProducts = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` 
NATURAL JOIN `catalog_product_flat_1`
where entity_id in (SELECT catalog_product_super_link.parent_id FROM `catalog_product_super_link` ) and type_id='configurable'");

$SimpleProduct = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` 
NATURAL JOIN `catalog_product_flat_1`
where entity_id not in (SELECT product_id FROM `catalog_product_super_link`) and type_id='simple'");

$AllProducts = array_merge($ConfigureProducts,$SimpleProduct);
foreach($AllProducts as $value)
{
    $title = $value['name'];
    $entity_id = $value['entity_id'];
    $result[] = array('value'=>$entity_id,'label'=>$title);
}
```